# Android 8.0 how to implement miracast sender app?

Tags: android, miracast

I want to implement the Miracast sender app on android 8.0. I refer to the google document

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarouter

but it only works for the device which support Google cast. it can not discover the device which support Miracast. but the picture in the document shows two devices include miracast device. why the device can not be discovered by sender app?

I noticed that Google has removed Miracast in Android 8.0, does this have impact on this situation?

Comment: anyone who can answer the question?

Comment: If you want an answer it might help to give more information here besides a link to dense documentation. Can you proof the device is discoverable in another way?

Comment: yes， I use android original feature "Multi-screen" maybe a different name on other android device. it can discover the miracast device rightly. so I am confused with this situation

Comment: It seems that the `MediaRouter` API only finds the preferred display. You should be able to manually enumerate displays with the `DisplayManager` API directly. See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation#choosing-a-presentation-display